# Turning arrowheads off

Tags: plotting, graphics, differential-equations

My thinking was that Arrowheads[0] would turn off the arrowheads.

```
vf = VectorPlot[{1, p*Exp[-p]}, {t, 0, 5}, {p, 0, 3},
  VectorScale -> {0.05, Automatic, None}, VectorPoints -> 20,
  VectorStyle -> {Gray, Arrowheads[0]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Which gives the following image.

[image]

Is my thinking incorrect?

Absolutely weird, look what happens when I reverse the order of Gray and Arrowheads[0], changing no other code.

```
vf = VectorPlot[{1, p*Exp[-p]}, {t, 0, 5}, {p, 0, 3},
  VectorScale -> {0.05, Automatic, None}, VectorPoints -> 20,
  VectorStyle -> {Arrowheads[0], Gray}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Is this a bug?

Running Version 10.0.1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of styles is the syntax for giving a series of styles to be applied cyclically to each of a series of plot elements.  For example:

```
VectorPlot[{{y, -x}, {x, y}}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 VectorStyle -> {Gray, Arrowheads[0]}]
```

[image]

Observe that one field gets `Gray` while the other gets `Arrowheads[0]`.  The correct syntax should be to use a sub-list (as Lou showed) or [`Directive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Directive.html), and here it works:

```
VectorPlot[{{y, -x}, {x, y}}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 VectorStyle -> {{Gray, Arrowheads[0]}, Red}]
```

[image]

Observe that this time one field gets both `Gray` and `Arrowheads[0]` while the other gets `Red`.

*However* I think there may be a bug in that order matters where I cannot see why it should.  This does not work the same as the plot above:

```
VectorPlot[{{y, -x}, {x, y}}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 VectorStyle -> {{Arrowheads[0], Gray}, Red}]
```

[image]

***Edit:*** In version 10.1.0 under Windows the output of this last command is the same as that of the penultimate one, so it looks like it was a bug and has since been fixed.

Comment: `Directive` in `VectorStyle` doesn't work with `Arrowheads` though. Mathematica 10.0.2 for Mac here.

Answer (score 3):

Set the style for vector fields:

```
vf = VectorPlot[{1, p*Exp[-p]}, {t, 0, 5}, {p, 0, 3}, 
  VectorScale -> {0.05, Automatic, None}, VectorPoints -> 20, 
  VectorStyle -> {{Red, Arrowheads[0]}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]